# Use of generics

Tags: java

I'm trying to expire objects from a hashmap if they haven't been used after some time.

I have maps on different types of objects and would like to handle them using generics to avoid code duplication.

```
private Map<String,EvictableObject<ObjectA>> _objectsA = new HashMap<String,EvictableObject<ObjectA>> ();
private Map<String,EvictableObject<ObjectB>> _objectsB = new HashMap<String,EvictableObject<ObjectB>> ();
private Map<String,EvictableObject<ObjectC>> _objectsC = new HashMap<String,EvictableObject<ObjectC>> ();
private Map<String,EvictableObject<ObjectD>> _objectsD = new HashMap<String,EvictableObject<ObjectD>> ();


private void startEvictionTask() {

    Runnable evictionTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run () {
            runEviction(_objectsA);
            runEviction(_objectsB);
            runEviction(_objectsC);
            runEviction(_objectsD);
        }

        private void runEviction (Map<String, EvictableObject<?>> table) {

            final long expirationPeriod = 60 * 60 * 1000; // 60 minutes (in ms)

            synchronized (table) {
                for (Map.Entry<String,EvictableObject<? extends Object>> entry : table.entrySet()) {
                    if (entry.getValue().getAccessedSince() > expirationPeriod)
                        table.remove(entry.getKey());
                }
            }

        }
    };

    MyThreadPool.getScheduledExecutor().scheduleWithFixedDelay(evictionTask, 65*60, 5*60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

But none of what I tried seem to work as a declaration of the runEviction method. And the compiler keeps saying that the actual argument can't be converted to the declared method parameter.

I've tried:

```
private void runEviction (Map<String, EvictableObject<?>> table)
```

,

```
private void runEviction (Map<String, EvictableObject<B>> table)
```

,

```
private void runEviction (Map<String, EvictableObject<B extends Object>> table)
```

and

```
private void runEviction (Map<String, EvictableObject<? extends Object>> table)
```

Is there no way to do this?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: `ObjectA` , `ObjectB`....so on..are different classes?? and each of them is extending nothing?

Comment: @Lee Meador I'm getting: runEviction(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,MyClass.EvictableObject>) in  cannot be applied to (java.util.Map<java.lang.String,MyClass.EvictableObject<ObjectA>>)

Comment: @VishalK yes they extend nothing, I would like to be able to treat any kind of Object if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making the `runEviction` method generic.

```
private <T> void runEviction (Map<String, EvictableObject<T>> table) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding type information to the runEviction method:

```
private <T> void runEviction(Map<String, EvitcableObject<T>> table) {}
```

Comment: In that case, accept the answer given by @rgettman. He got here just before me.

Answer (score 1):

The prior answers are good. (+1 on both)

But I want to add a couple of suggestions. Perhaps we can argue about them.

Notice that I added a new Class or Interface `ObjectBase` that all the `ObjectX` classes have to extend (or implement). The advantage here is that it makes it more deliberate and keeps future maintainers' changes on the straight and narrow. It does depend on your object hierarchy which you want to choose. This keeps from making any old object `Evictable`. (Perhaps you need to make `String` objects evictable. In that case, this won't work.)

*This makes me wonder if a better name for `ObjectBase` would be `Evictable` is it's an interface. Probably ...*

But you need this in `EvictableObject` to make that parent class (or interface) thing work:

```
public class EvictableObject<T extends ObjectBase>
```

Of course, you have noticed that you have to change the one line to:

```
 for (Map.Entry<String,EvictableObject<T>> entry : table.entrySet())
```

since the `T` is needed there.

The whole new code is here.

```
    private Map<String,EvictableObject<ObjectA>> _objectsA = new HashMap<String,EvictableObject<ObjectA>> ();
    private Map<String,EvictableObject<ObjectB>> _objectsB = new HashMap<String,EvictableObject<ObjectB>> ();
    private Map<String,EvictableObject<ObjectC>> _objectsC = new HashMap<String,EvictableObject<ObjectC>> ();
    private Map<String,EvictableObject<ObjectD>> _objectsD = new HashMap<String,EvictableObject<ObjectD>> ();

    private void startEvictionTask() {

        Runnable evictionTask = new Runnable() {
            public void run () {
                runEviction(_objectsA);
                runEviction(_objectsB);
                runEviction(_objectsC);
                runEviction(_objectsD);
            }

            private <T extends ObjectBase> void runEviction (Map<String, EvictableObject<T>> table) {

                final long expirationPeriod = 60 * 60 * 1000; // 60 minutes (in ms)

                synchronized (table) {
                    for (Map.Entry<String,EvictableObject<T>> entry : table.entrySet()) {
                        if (entry.getValue().getAccessedSince() > expirationPeriod)
                            table.remove(entry.getKey());
                    }
                }

            }
        };

        new Thread(evictionTask).start();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I had thought about making my evictable objects implement the Evictable interface. If so I would not need to use generics at all, I could just use EvictableObject<Evictable>, but I don't like this because in my opinion the Evictable interface doesn't bring anything (at least not to me). If it had a method to release some resource, yes, definitely. But I prefer not over-specifying object when it's not required.